# Removed my USB drivers and now I can’t use mouse or keyboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

My USB drive wasn’t loading properly, so I uninstalled the USB drivers. Now my keyboard and mouse don’t work once the computer boots into windows. What can I do?

**UPDATE:** Managed to do a system restore from the startup repair thing. Would still like to know how to get our of this situation without doing that.

Comment: Got a PS/2 Mouse and Keyboard ? Got PS/2 ports ? Use those ?

Comment: No and no unfortunately

Comment: RDP into your PC to reinstall the drivers ?

Comment: maybe boot in safe mode? The BIOS should still support your keyboard to select safe mode. Or maybe even command prompt?

Comment: I couldn't use anything in safemode either. What can I do Rob the command prompt?

Comment: I'd setup RDP so that if it happens, you can remote in without local input.

Answer (score 2):

If the rest of your PC is operating correctly, I would install an expansion USB card. When the computer boots up, it should install drivers for common chipset with no problem. Though you mentioned logging in, I'm under the impression that you should still get basic USB function for keyboard and mouse.

Failing that, if you have a USB 3.0 header, you can plug a USB 2.0 device in USB 3.0 socket and the USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 run off different controllers so should hopefully give you enough love to login and restore your old drivers.

Last is the Windows disk as you mentioned as it will load drivers from the disk, though it's always messy do a system repair as sometimes it breaks more than it fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Since USB is recognized when you plug it in, trying unplugging both mouse and keyboard. Turn off computer. Wait one minute, then turn on computer. Wait till everything is done loading, and plug both in again. Windows should recognize the usb connections and reinstall usb drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in an old keyboard, not using usb, restart and find/finnish installs. Worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Plug in an old keyboard, not using usb, restart and find/finnish installs. Worked fine for me

Its perfectly working for the mean time that the usb port couldn't recognized, the old or PS/2 port was able to recognized because categorically different port.

I hope you get my point to help you also with these scenario that worked for me. :)

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is an exact duplicate of [another answer](https://superuser.com/q/753657/150988#1147806). I can’t tell what the rest of this answer is — are you adding something to the previous answer, or are you saying “thank you”.  In the first case, please [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.  In the second case, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following method worked for me and maybe work for people with the same problem too. 
Restart your computer and press F8 to see 'Advanced Boot Options' and choose 'Last known good configuration'. I have windows 7 and I don't know if you should use another key to see that page in other windows versions. Also after repairing your computer, don't forget about enabling 'System Restore'.

Answer (score -1):

Try solve this through Device Manager. Uninstall all USB controllers and then "check for hardware changes". It should solve the problem.

Comment: I can't login without my mouse or keyboard

Comment: And how is he supposed to do this?!

Answer (score -1):

Use another computer to remote desktop onto your PC. That will allow you to access device manager to re-install the USB controller/drivers

Comment: Remote desktop isn't set up

Comment: At all ? Have you tried ?